# Function from list of parameters

Tags: python, function

can you please help me with my python code? I wanted to parse several homepages with beautiful soup provided in the list html with the function stars

```
html=["https://www.onvista.de/aktien/fundamental/Adidas-Aktie-DE000A1EWWW0", "https://www.onvista.de/aktien/fundamental/Allianz-Aktie-DE0008404005", "https://www.onvista.de/aktien/fundamental/BASF-Aktie-DE000BASF111"]

def stars(html):
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
    starbewertung = bsObj.findAll("section")[8].findAll("div")[1].findAll("span")[16]

    str_cells = str(starbewertung)
    cleantext = BeautifulSoup(str_cells, "lxml").get_text()
    print(cleantext)


    lst=[]
    lst.append(cleantext)

stars(html)
```

Instead I am getting an error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'"

Comment: After that you'll get a `NameError` - your list `html` has no method `read()` so this: `html.read(...)` won't work. Unclear what your problem is - voting to close until this gets more clear. You probably should have some loop that does something to your global _html_ and calls your funtion providing a lokal _html_ string?

Comment: You can try with format: `BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')` with `html` can be got by using `requests` library

Comment: Seems what you're trying to do is get the html from the URLs listed in `html` variable. But what you did within the function (`html.read()`) is not how you can do that. You can loop through the list and use `requests` package to get html code from each URL and then use BeautifulSoup to find whatever you need to find in that html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some of the comments mentioned you need to use the [requests library](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/) to actually grab the content of each link in your list.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html=["https://www.onvista.de/aktien/fundamental/Adidas-Aktie-DE000A1EWWW0", "https://www.onvista.de/aktien/fundamental/Allianz-Aktie-DE0008404005", "https://www.onvista.de/aktien/fundamental/BASF-Aktie-DE000BASF111"]

def stars(html):
    for url in html:
        resp = requests.get(url)
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')
        print(bsObj) # Should print the entire html document.
        # Do other stuff with bsObj here.

stars(html)
```

The IndexError from `bsObj.findAll("section")[8].findAll("div")[1].findAll("span")[16]` is something you'll need to figure out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors here.

1. you are trying to load the whole list of pages into BeautifulSoup. You should process page by page.
2. You should get the source code of the page before processing it.
3. there is no "section" element on the page you are loading, so you will get an exception as you are trying to get the 8th element. So you might need to evaluate whether you found anything.

```
def stars(html):
    request = requests.get(html)
    if request.status_code != 200:
        return
    page_content = request.content
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(page_content)
    starbewertung = bsObj.findAll("section")[8].findAll("div")[1].findAll("span")[16]

    str_cells = str(starbewertung)
    cleantext = BeautifulSoup(str_cells, "lxml").get_text()
    print(cleantext)

for page in html:
    stars(page)
```